# Magento override class in onepageController.php

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I have a problem overriding the controller:

> \app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\controllers\OnepageController.php

I tried to do it by creating new file here:

> \app\code\local\Mage\Checkout\controllers\OnepageController.php

nothing happened.

Then I tried to do it by creating new plugin :

path : \app\etc\modules\MyExtensions_Checkout.xml

```
<config>
<modules>
    <MyExtensions_Checkout>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
        <depends>
            <Mage_Checkout/>
        </depends>
    </MyExtensions_Checkout>
</modules>
```

path : \app\code\local\MyExtensions\etc\config.xml

```
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <checkout>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <MyExtensions_Checkout before="Mage_Checkout">MyExtensions_Checkout</MyExtensions_Checkout>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </checkout>
    </routers>
</frontend>
```

path: app\code\local\MyExtensions\Checkout\controllers\CartController.php

```
class MyExtensions_Checkout_CartController extends Mage_Checkout_Controller_Action{}
```

Module is appearing in admin panel but overriding still doesn't work.
What is wrong with my code ? 
Thx in advance.

Comment: what are you trying to override out of it?

Comment: Just removing some lines I don't need. Is it matter somehow ?
I can't write it here in comment because it's too long but basicaly I'm removing shiping method.

Comment: Basically, if you override attemp in local pool have failed, it's because, another module is overriding it.
Try to disable this one and test again.

Comment: @MaxBongiorno Thank you it was good idea to check module conflicts, I disabled all installed ones but unfortunately it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issue fixed.**

I'm sorry, that was my fault, I had one more folder inside my Extention
So I just changed :

```
path : \app\code\local\MyExtensions\etc\config.xml
```

to

```
path : \app\code\local\MyExtensions\Checkout\etc\config.xml
```

Thank you everyone for help!

Answer (score 0):

path : \app\etc\modules\MyExtensions_Checkout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config>
  <modules>
    <MyExtensions_Checkout>
     <version>1.0</version>
    </MyExtensions_Checkout>
  </modules>

  <frontend>
   <routers>
    <checkout>
     <args>
      <modules>
        <MyExtensions_Checkout before="Mage_Checkout">MyExtensions_Checkout</MyExtensions_Checkout>
      </modules>
     </args>
    </checkout>
   </routers>
 </frontend>
 </config>
```

path: app\code\local\MyExtensions\Checkout\controllers\OnepageController.php

```
require_once 'Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php';
class MyExtensions_Checkout_OnepageController extends Mage_Checkout_Controller_Action{}
```

Comment: Thank you for code but it doesn't work for me. Any different solutions ?

Comment: no, it just don't work. If I change core file it work perfectly.
I'm trying reduce steps, therefore if I won't remove some lines it wouldn't let me to next step because of opcheckout.js that taking ajax parametres from the OnepageController line.